# How do I populate Google Form questions using column A data from different Google Sheets Tabs using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to populate Google Form questions from a Google Sheet workbook using Apps Script. The issue I'm running into is that the Form isn't populating and I'm getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined specifically on the line googleSheetsQuestions[0].  How can I populate the 2 questions on my Google Form using only column A values from both Sheets?

```
function openForm(e)
{
  populateQuestions();
}

function populateQuestions() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues();
  var itemsArray = form.getItems();
  itemsArray.forEach(function(item){
    googleSheetsQuestions[0].forEach(function(header_value, header_index) {
      if(header_value == item.getTitle())
      {
        var choiceArray = [];
        for(j = 1; j < googleSheetsQuestions.length; j++)
        {
          (googleSheetsQuestions[j][header_index] != '') ? choiceArray.push(googleSheetsQuestions[j][header_index]) : null;
        }
        item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choiceArray);
      }
    });     
  });
}

function getQuestionValues() {
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890');
["Sheet1", "Sheet2"].forEach(function (s) {
    var questionSheet = ss.getSheetByName(s);
    var returnData = questionSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    debugger;
    return returnData;
})
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. When I saw your showing script, I think that `googleSheetsQuestions` of `var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues();` is undefined. So I cannot understand `he issue I'm running into is that the Form isn't populating due to (I believe) the return values being 4 columns (A-D) when I only have 2 questions pointing to the Column A headers on the Form.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry I have updated the question. Essentially my form isn't populating the 2 questions I have. Column A on the 2 Sheet tabs should populate checkbox options on my Google Form but nothing is happening. I keep getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I keep getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, I have already commented. In your question, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the images? Because from your showing script, I cannot understand the relationship between your script and your goal. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, can you provide more information to correctly understand your question?

Comment: @Tanaike the goal is to populate checkbox options in my Google Form using the data that is in all the cells within Column A of both of my Sheet tabs. I was trying to create a loop that goes through the columns and when it finds the data it puts it in the Google Form question that matches the header title.

Comment: Could you provide a sample document containing sample data? @BrookeTaylor

Comment: @OctaviaSima I have updated my question with screenshots of what I'm working with. Unfortunately I am on my work computer so it won't let me share outside of our organization. But as you can see in the screenshots, I have 2 questions on my form with the same headers as the ones in sheet 1 and sheet 2. I'm trying to populate those questions with the data within those columns.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your added information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful and I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function populateQuestions() {
  // Retrieve values from Google Spreadsheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890');
  var obj = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"].reduce((o, s) => {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(s);
    var [h, ...values] = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    o[h] = values;
    return o;
  }, {});
  
  // Put values to the Google Form.
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var itemsArray = form.getItems();
  itemsArray.forEach(e => {
    var item = e.asCheckboxItem();
    var title = item.getTitle();
    if (obj[title]) {
      item.setChoiceValues(obj[title]);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from 2 sheets of Google Spreadsheet, and the retrieved values are put into the Google Form.
- In your showing script, `googleSheetsQuestions` of `var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues();` is always `undefined`. From your goal, in this case, I used an object for searching the title of the question.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, please confirm whether the title of Google Form is the same with the values of "A1" of each sheet, again.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much especially for your explanation!

Comment: @Brooke Taylor Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.  With your cooperation, I could correctly understand your question and think of a solution. Thank you, too.